# monitor days the user is on the page

Tags: javascript, php

I want to track that the user has played the game on my website for 15 minutes per day and for continuous 10 days if he misses one day then his needs to again start from day 1 using JavaScript and PHP.

I am getting stuck in the idea that how we can track the 15 minutes a day and 10 days for a specific user.

Comment: Show us what you currently have

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: You need server side user sessions and a persistent data storage for this, so a database where you track periods of activity of accounts.

Comment: currently i have not started any coding for the same

Comment: could you be more specific in technical terms wat i need to do as I am a beginner in development

Answer (score 0):

As @arkascha mentioned, tracking user involves using sessions and saving data to permanent storage (you can save into file for first time, but learn DB management - PHP is closely tied with this one)

But before that you need to ask YOURSELF with few questions

1. Why do need to check data about users on your site? Remember that most of time users don't spend on web page, maybe it's better to check their requests to your site?
2. What type of network environment you're using. Is your website is opened for entire world (e.g. Internet) or you're located in small network with network access rules?
3. How you should identify your users? By IP or some kind of name?
   Answering 3rd question can be done via requesting `phpinfo()` function and checking following variables `$_SERVER['USERNAME'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`
4. Learn sessions (start from manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

And remember - you should ask questions about particular problems (for example, "Session variables are not storing on PHP 7.x, Ubuntu XX, Apache 2.4.x"), NOT general ones (please write the code for me)

Comment: Appreciate your response...i'll try to do that....if i have some issue i will get in touch